# What are the consequences of installing CWM?

Tags: rooting, clockworkmod-recovery, fastboot

I installed CWM sometime back and switched back to a stock ROM. When I installed CWM I lost my userdata, by which I mean the phone started as it would for the first time after opening the box. I used `fastboot oem unlock` to unlock the bootloader so I could install CWM.

I want to root my phone, but I don't want to lose all my userdata this time. Is CWM is a must for rooting?

Comment: It depends, what device are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by userdata? Has you device gone in factory reset status or you lost data from SD card?

Comment: Sorry, but what model of you device? I'm firstly hear about lost data, but it may be because of script error or _fastboot oem unlock_ command, where it already unneeded (it needed first time, and it format userdata for security reason).

Comment: live with walkman sony...(wt19i)

Comment: yes..I lost all contacts and apps etc...I lost my personal words keyboard learnt sofar..that was most painful

Comment: @Penguinolog I think that answers my question...I did fastboot oem unlock then installed CWM..

Comment: i have 2 android phones.. I have never seen this case "After installing CWM I lost data!" . Check if you tried to do Factory reset via CWM! if you did Factory reset that might have caused you to loose userdata.

Comment: As [Liam's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/33887/16575) makes clear, the factory-reset came from `fastboot oem unlock`, not from installing CWM. Moreover, flashing stock ROM does not necessarily mean CWM is gone: `/recovery` is a separate partition. So unless stock *recovery* was flashed, CWM should still be there.

Answer (score 3):

1. `fastboot oem unlock` always deletes userdata for security reasons, so it must be used only once (until you lock again manually).
2. CWM is needed if you want to flash a root package (you can't push it via fastboot), but that is not usually the only way to root a device.  The CWM install needs only the `fastboot flash recovery recovery_name` command, which does not affect user data.

Comment: Root application not flash - it realy put into flashed system.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you lost your user data was because of the oem unlock command - the documentation says this will erase all user data for security.

You can install cwm using fastboot `fastboot flash recovery <path to recovery image>`, and to will not erase userdata.

Recovery isn't a must for root - but it is recommended.